# Bit data type column output from mysqldump (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, output, bit

I'm using bit(1) to represent a boolean but when I dump the table into a file using mysqldump, the outputted data doesn't appear in the format that I expect.

What I see in the table (phpMyAdmin):

```
0    1
```

What I see in the file (mysqldump):

```
SOH    \0
```

What I see if I use the export feature of phpMyAdmin:

```
b'0'    b'1'
```

Do I need to use a flag or is this a safe representation of the bit data type?

Comment: Without knowing what you did to write the data to file, I can suggest that possibly you are just looking at some binary data.  I wouldn't worry about this, unless you can't read in the data correctly.  If you need to present the data a certain way, then just save the output from a query.

Comment: I wrote the data into the table via phpmyadmin. It is displayed as I wrote it there but the outputted data on the SQL file looks weird like that.

Answer (score 6):

Add `--hex-blob` option to your mysqldump command.

It means dump binary columns using hexadecimal notation. Then it becomes human-readable in your file.

Comment: Thank you! Works well! One question about your answer: If I have `SOH` is the dump corrupt or can I restore the data even is there a `SOH` in the dump?

Comment: @KevinO. the `SOH` value should not affect the restore process.